# How can rpy2 (R code from python) be run in a thread without blocking other threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, rpy2

**Problem summary**

I am trying to run R code from python using `rpy2` in a second thread (not `multiprocessing`, just a thread is fine), but it seems to keep blocking my main thread. Can this be avoided?

---

**My original code:**

```
import time
import threading
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

def long_r_function():
    robjects.r('Sys.sleep(10)')    # pretend we have a long-running function in R

r_thread = threading.Thread(target=long_r_function, daemon=True)
start_time = time.time()
r_thread.start()

while r_thread.is_alive():
    print("R running...")    # expect to be able to see this print from main thread, 
    time.sleep(2)            # while R does work in second thread

print("Finished after ", time.time() - start_time, " seconds")
```

**Expected output:**

I'd expect to see 5 "`R running`" prints, because the main thread shouldn't get blocked while R is sleeping for 10 seconds.

**Actual output:**

A single print where I expected 5:

```
R running...
Finished after  12.006645679473877  seconds
```

---

**Moving `rpy2.objects` import into thread's target function:**

Because the `import rpy2.robjects as robjects` statement already causes the R environment to be initialized, I figured it might help to move this into the thread's target function `long_r_function`, to see if that would somehow decouple it from the main thread. **This did not work**.

---

**Replacing `rpy2` code with python code**:

Just as a sanity check, if I completely get rid of the `rpy2` code and instead define the thread's target function as

```
def long_r_function():
    time.sleep(10)
```

I correctly get the expected output (which is now lying because there isn't any R running):

```
R running...
R running...
R running...
R running...
R running...
Finished after  10.002039194107056  seconds
```

---

**Update: rpy2 in main thread also blocks second thread**

When I switch the threads around with the following code, such that `rpy2` runs R code in the main thread and I try to see if python can still do something in a second thread, the same issue occurs.

```
def print_and_sleep():
    while True:
        print("Second thread running...")
        time.sleep(2)

py_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_and_sleep, daemon=True)
py_thread.start()
robjects.r('Sys.sleep(10)')
```

Output: only one or two prints of `"Second thread running..."`, instead of the expected 5. Again, works fine with a similar sanity check to the one above, where `rpy2` is replaced with just python code.

So, this is not specific to the main thread. It seems like `rpy2` simply blocks all python threads, regardless of where it's running?

---

**Version info**:

```
rpy2.__version__ = 2.8.5
rpy2.rinterface.R_VERSION_BUILD = ('3', '3.2', '', 71607)
sys.version = 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses a lock (known as the GIL) to prevent the concurrent execution of bytecode, and when calling C (which is what is happening when executing R code through rpy2) by default the GIL is not released until that code returns.

Now it is possible to release the GIL from within a C extension **but** R is very unfriendly to multithreading (as in "will segfault really quickly"). Because of this, the effort to implement a release of the GIL and handle all possible ways where concurrent evaluation of R could happen did not feel worth it.

If the purpose is to parallelize R code with rpy2, use processes rather an than thread (for example using Python's `multiprocessing`).

Comment: The purpose is not to parallelize R code in this way, the purpose is to have a python-based GUI keep track of and show progress (because my R code is supposed to create a bunch of files in a specific dir, I can do this simply by counting in python how many files have already been created. So, even this wont be possible without `multiprocessing`?

Comment: You could call your python function performing the update from R (using this to pass the Python function to R: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/rinterface.html#calling-python-functions-from-r).

Comment: I see. I'm not very familiar with R though, just running code written by someone else, so that'd be a bit annoying. I also kind of want a responsive python GUI, so it should receive frequent ticks. Ended up just going with multiprocessing instead of threading; a bit overkill when otherwise a thread would be sufficient, but it does work

Answer (score 1):

Igautier's answer explains why this turns out to be difficult technically. The best way to achieve the intended goal appears to be using `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`, even if threads would be sufficient otherwise. The code then looks as follows:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def long_r_function():
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
    robjects.r('Sys.sleep(10)')    # pretend we have a long-running function in R

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r_process = Process(target=long_r_function)
    start_time = time.time()
    r_process.start()

    while r_process.is_alive():
        print("R running...")    # expect to be able to see this print from main process,
        time.sleep(2)            # while R does work in second process

    print("Finished after ", time.time() - start_time, " seconds")
```

Which gives the output as intended (often 6 or 7 prints instead of 5 due to overhead of creating a new process):

```
R running...
R running...
R running...
R running...
R running...
R running...
Finished after  12.413572311401367  seconds
```